# Will installing cyanogenmod7 on my Samsung Vibrant require me to wipe my phone first?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-vibrant

I'm interested in putting CyanogenMod on my Samsung Vibrant (Galaxy S).  The [FAQ](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/FAQ) on Cyanogenmod says:

> Q: Do I have to wipe my data before I install CyanogenMod?
>
> A: Short answer: Maybe. Long answer: Maybe.

I understand there's a possibility if something goes wrong that I might have to wipe my phone.  However, in the [Vibrant instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Vibrant%3a_Full_Update_Guide) right after booting into ClockworkMod Recovery it says to "wipe data/factory reset" and "wipe cache partition".  That seems to me to indicate that a factory reset is required, which I would think would wipe out everything on my phone.

Is it just that the Vibrant's instruction require a reset or am I not understanding something?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, yes.  I tried without wiping and CM7 failed to boot.

Comment: My experience, too. I tried once and I boot-looped. I tried a different time and it booted, but practically everything I opened force closed.